# pandas merge row cells of same value into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas dataframe `FruitsInfo` as shown :

```
====================================
|  Name  |  Color  |  Size  |  No. |
====================================
| Apple  |  Red    | Medium |  20  |
------------------------------------
| Apple  | Green   | Small  |  10  |
------------------------------------
| Apple  | Yellow  | Small  |   5  |
------------------------------------
| Grapes | Green   | Small  |  50  |
------------------------------------
| Grapes | Purple  | Small  |  60  |
------------------------------------
| Grapes | Black   | Medium |  80  |
------------------------------------
| Mango  | Yellow  | Medium |  30  |
------------------------------------
| Mango  | Green   | Small  |  25  |
------------------------------------
| Mango  | Orange  | Small  |  20  |
====================================
```

I want to merge only `Name` column as shown below. How can I get this result using pandas ?

```
====================================
|  Name  |  Color  |  Size  |  No. |
====================================
| Apple  |  Red    | Medium |  20  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Green   | Small  |  10  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Yellow  | Small  |   5  |
------------------------------------
| Grapes | Green   | Small  |  50  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Purple  | Small  |  60  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Black   | Medium |  80  |
------------------------------------
| Mango  | Yellow  | Medium |  30  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Green   | Small  |  25  |
|        ---------------------------
|        | Orange  | Small  |  20  |
====================================
```

Comment: you tried group?

Comment: this looks more like indexing...

Comment: `df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Color'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont really understand what do you mean by grouping, but it seems like you got a multi index dataframe the represnted in prints like this so you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
csv = io.StringIO('''|  Name  |  Color  |  Size  |  No. |
| Apple  |  Red    | Medium |  20  |
| Apple  | Green   | Small  |  10  |
| Apple  | Yellow  | Small  |   5  |
| Grapes | Green   | Small  |  50  |
| Grapes | Purple  | Small  |  60  |
| Grapes | Black   | Medium |  80  |
| Mango  | Yellow  | Medium |  30  |
| Mango  | Green   | Small  |  25  |
| Mango  | Orange  | Small  |  20  |''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv,sep=r'\s*\|\s*').iloc[:,1:-1]
>>>df.set_index(['Name','Color'])
                Size    No.
Name    Color       
Apple   Red     Medium  20
        Green   Small   10
        Yellow  Small   5
Grapes  Green   Small   50
        Purple  Small   60
        Black   Medium  80
Mango   Yellow  Medium  30
        Green   Small   25
        Orange  Small   20
```

Comment: Ok.  Initially I had run only  `df.set_index(['Name'])`.  Now Running `df.set_index(['Name','Color'])` worked. Thanks.

Comment: can I ask for what propose you need that?

Comment: Just to make it more readable after converting into html table using `df.to_html()` .